# Using NPP, is there a method to numerically sort values separated by commas (single column)?

Tags: notepad++, csv, sorting, plugins, nppexec

I have a large JSON csv file of values (one column). In order to remove duplicates, I need to first Replace All CRs then use TextFX Sort Lines function, then Replace All the CRs with commas (such that the JSON file is back in good order). **Is there a NPP plugin or NPP method I can use to simply sort the comma-separated values such that duplicates are removed?** Sample list:

12345,98765,12345,11111,12345

Needs to be:

11111,12345,98765

The sorting is unimportant, the deduping is what I need

Comment: Python and Excel both have ways to handle this, might be options for a single occasion.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use it for a few occasions or JSON files, I recommend using the functions available in Notepad++ (e.g. Version 7.8.7 64bit).

You know, first replace the commas with line breaks:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `,`
- Replace with: `\r\n`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Extended*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[image]

The dialogue can be closed if desired (optional: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>).

In two further steps from the main menu you sort the lines and delete the duplicates.

1. Edit > Line Operations > Sort Lines As Integers Ascending
2. Edit > Line Operations > Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines

Finally, the commas are inserted again.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\r\n`
- Replace with: `,`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the above, but that already what I am doing at it is far too cumbersome (slow). I am looking for a way to sort out duplicates withOUT having to Find&Replace commas with CRLFs